# How to arrange charges on a 1d line so that the electric field along the line far away is r^-6?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

My question is simple: How to arrange charges on a 1d line so that the electric field along the line far away is r^-6?e.g., we can make field falling as r^-3 by two charges(dipole field).

This type of problems are essential in getting the desired potential function from a source. I want r^-5 potential in this case.

In particular, i'm looking for a tricky solution for this type of potential sources without too much caculations.

Comment: I'm not sure if this agrees with the site's [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). It might be better received if you mention what you've already tried.

Comment: Have you seen anything about dipoles before? Or [quadrupoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole) or even higher order multipoles?

Comment: @jacob1729 I've edited my question to specify what actually i'm looking for.